# What does "as it landed" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> A flock of birds shattered the windshields of a Malaysia Airlines jet
>   **as it landed** in the Nepali capital, Kathmandu, but all 180 passengers and crew were safe, an airport official said on Sunday.

From this [page](http://www.newindianexpress.com/world/Malaysia-Airlines-Flight-to-Nepal-Hit-by-Birds-Passengers-Safe/2014/03/23/article2126113.ece#.Uy79rX1uvMI).

Which of the following does this mean?

> 1)  while it was landing in the capital. Actually the Nepali capital
>   was its destination.

or

> 2) it had to land there. Actually it was not its destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has your first meaning, "while it was landing in ... Kathmandu".

It *could* mean "because it landed ... in Kathmandu", but that would be very unlikely. I cannot imagine circumstances which would lead to that interpretation. If there were such circumstances it would surely be mentioned in the lede.

In either case there is no trace of a suggestion that this was a forced landing or that Kathmandu was not the destination.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "as it landed" does not, of itself, indicate whether this was the intended destination or not.

However, the fact that the birds struck the plane "as it landed" seems to indicate that the plane was already in the process of landing before the accident happened. The accident could not have caused them to choose this destination if they were already landing there before it happened.

Perhaps you are confused because "as" can also mean "because"? For example, if someone said, "We had to go through Nepalese customs, as we landed in Katmandu", that means "because we landed in Katmandu". But the causation here would be in the opposite direction from what you're suggesting. "As ..." indicates that what follows is the cause, not the result. If the writer had said, "We landed in Katmandu, as birds had damaged the plane", that would mean that the damage caused by the birds forced us to land in Katmandu. But that's not the wording here.